# iOS Core Data - Does fetching one entity objects automatically fetch all objects from relation entities?

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have entity **City**.

I have other entities: **BankBranches**, **NotaryBranches** etc. These entities are relations **many-to-one** with **City** entity. Also **City** entity has **one-to-many** relation with those entities.

So, if I fetch only city names of City entity, does those entity objects also fetched? I'm warning about fetch performance, cause some times I want get only city names, not touching all other related objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Core Data uses a mechanism called "faulting" to reduce the amount of memory used.  There's a description of how it works at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html

Comment: Namely, if I fetch city.bankBranches, only in this situation core data will fetch all bankBranches and store them in memory?!

Comment: That's how it generally works.  You can test it yourself in the debugger by typing "po city" before and after referencing its relationship.  First, it should show the fault information and, after that, the actual objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only searching for city names, i would suggest to even more efficient on your fetch by using the setPropertiesToFetch: method of your NSFetchRequest instance. You will assign a NSPropertyDescription representing the name. Here's how it works:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSDictionary *properties=[entity propertiesByName];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[properties valueForKey:@"yourPropertyName"]]];
```

Using this fetch request, you will get a dictionary for each object fetched, and the only property you get is the one you fetched. The only drawback of this method is that you will not be able to use NSFetchedResultsController on a full persistent tracking mode. Basically, you get no tracking mode from the NSFetchedResultsController using this.